# Testing if object Is Nothing results in 'Object required' error

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am supporting some classic ASP pages, one of which uses and re-uses an object **conn** and disposes of it either when the .asp page finishes processing or right before the page redirects to another page.

```
<%
dim conn
...
set conn = server.CreateObject("adodb.connection")
...
sub cleanUp()
    conn.Close
    set conn = nothing
end sub
...
sub pageRedirect(url)
    call cleanUp()
    response.Redirect url : response.End
end sub
...
' very end of file
call cleanUp()%>
```

I've found that if there is a redirect, I get a server error right at the line `conn.Close`, *Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' Object required*. I figure there's no reason why that line would execute more than once but to be safe I rewrote the function

```
sub cleanUp()
    if(not (conn Is Nothing)) then
        conn.Close
        set conn = Nothing
    end if
end sub
```

But I still get that exact error, now at the line `if(not (conn Is Nothing))`!! I thought the purpose of `Is Nothing` was to do a test before using the variable name conn precisely to prevent that 'object required' error, but the test is throwing the same error.

What other test can I use to make sure conn isn't referenced if it'd already been set to Nothing?

Comment: Give space after **`if`** condition **`"if (not ("`**

Comment: Empty is for value variables, Nothing is for objects. conn is an object. And spacing doesn't matter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`is nothing` is used to test for an object reference, if the variable does not contain such then the test is invalid & raises an error, so `conn` can only be tested after its been `set` to something.

You can;

```
if isobject(conn) then
   if not (conn Is Nothing) then set conn = nothing
end if
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Setting my objects to nothing right after they're declared is also a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use option explicit (each time a script runs without option explicit, a puppie dies out there), you probably would have detected the problem earlier as Nilpo mentioned.
2. When you dim a variable that you are going to use as an object reference and test it on Nothing, make it a habbit to set it to Nothing at initialization time(*): `dim myObject : Set myObject = Nothing`.

(*) Not really at initialization, because the dim's are handled before a routine starts, but when you put all your dim's at the top of a routine, it will practically be the same.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `IsNothing` function.  You should also check that it is an object.

```
sub cleanUp()
    if Not IsNothing(conn) then
        if IsObject(conn) then
            conn.Close
        end if
        set conn = nothing
    end if
end sub
```

That being said, I would do it like this since setting a variable to nothing does no harm.

```
sub cleanUp()
    if IsObject(conn) then
        conn.Close
    end if
    set conn = nothing
end sub
```

More importantly though, your problem is that `conn` is not in scope for your subroutine.  You should probably pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: is there a reference for the `IsNothing` function?

Comment: There is no `IsNothing` function. You must use `Is Nothing` in a statement, such as:

`if obj Is Nothing then
    ' do stuff
end if`